# How to set a UITextField to edit severals lines?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, editing

I have a UITextField that is 300px width and 270px height. When I want to edit it, the cursor goes automatically in the middle and I can only write on the middle line.
How can I set this UITextField to have severals lines and a cursor starting at the top-left ?

Comment: use UITextView with your fixed frame size..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, just use `UITextView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

UITextfield is designed for single line only, If you want to enter multi line text than use UITextView instead and set its editable property to YES than it would behave like textfield!

```
[myTextView setEditable:YES];
```

Note: You can also set it via Interface Builder, select the "editable" box & It will be multiline by default.